# Placing javascript code in an HTML code line doesn't work

Tags: php, javascript, html

JavaScript won't accept the code below, whats wrong?

```
<a href="#" <?php if ($tagOn) {echo 'id="tagOn"' } else {echo 'id="tagOff"'  } ?>
  onclick="addToSearch('xyz')">Xyz</a>
```

`$tagOn` is a Boolean.

Comment: You are missing semicolons after echo statements.

Answer (score 3):

I think it's clearer if you define the variable first.  It gets confusing if you put too much logic inline.

```
<?php $id = $tagOn ? "tagOn" : "tagOff"; ?>

<a href="#" "<?php echo $id ?> onclick="addToSearch('xyz')">Xyz</a>
```

Comment: I don't see this setting the `id`

Comment: Thanks all - it was the semicolons :p

Answer (score 0):

You're forgetting the semi-colons after each statement, try something like this:

```
<a href="#" <?php if ($tagOn) { echo 'id="tagOn"'; } else { echo 'id="tagOff"';  }  ?>
  onclick="addToSearch('xyz')">Xyz</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

It *might* just be the missing semi-colons

```
<a href="#" <?php if ($tagOn) { echo 'id="tagOn"'; } else { echo 'id="tagOff"';  }  ?>
  onclick="addToSearch('xyz')">Xyz</a>
```

A cleaner way of doing this is with the ternary operator:

```
<a href="#" id=<?php echo ($tagOn) ? '"tagOn"' : '"tagOff"'; ?>
  onclick="addToSearch('xyz')">Xyz</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You forget semicolons !

```
<a href="#" <?php if ($tagOn) { echo 'id="tagOn"'; } else { echo 'id="tagOff"';  }  ?>
  onclick="addToSearch('xyz')">Xyz</a>
```